# Properties page for MFC dialog include file shows empty in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm working on an MFC project and when I go to the .h file of any dialog, the Properties page is empty, so I cannot access the event handlers, overrides, etc. quickly.

I think it's happened before, and I was able to resolve it, but this time I cannot seem to do it.

I've tried cleaning the solution and deleting all the temp files (ncb, pdb, ilk, aps...), disabling add-ins...

Actually, I've even created a new dialog-based application solution, and I get the same empty properties page, so I think it's something that's gone wrong in Visual Studio (or some add-in).

Any ideas how to solve this?

---

**UPDATE:**
Actually, it is empty for both .cpp and .h files of any kind, not just for dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I'll answer my own question for reference.

I have Visual Assist installed, and the other day it offered me to disable Visual Studio's Navigation Bar (I think that's its name; my IDE is in Spanish and it's "Barra de Navegación") because Visual Assist has its own and it's more powerful. So I disabled it. I had not noticed the issue with the properties page until I needed it, of course.

Now I've enabled the Navigation Bar again and the Properties page is working fine. I've also disabled the Navigation Bar again, and it seems to work fine.